# Why does VB6 replace msxml3.dll with msxml6.dll in my project on Windows 8.1?

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 project that I've always worked with in a Windows XP VM.  I've decided to go ahead and install VB6 on my Windows 8.1 box.

I opened the project and right off the bat it didn't compile.  It was complaining that `DOMDocument` could not be found.  I looked in referenced and noticed instead of `Microsoft XML, v3.0`, it had `Microsoft XML, v6.0` selected.  In that library, it has a `DOMDocument60` object, but not `DOMDocument` object.

I tried referencing both v3.0 and v6.0, but it prevents me from doing that, claiming a name conflict.

So my questions.

1. Why is it referencing a different library?
2. What can I do to make sure that the project always references v3.0 regardless of the OS?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744084/vb6-project-references/7744826#7744826

Comment: MSXML 3.0 is still present and working even in Windows 10.  Have you tried changing the reference back to the correct DLL?  I have no idea what might have changed it to 6.0 automatically and I haven't seen this occur myself.

Comment: Yes, if I change it manually, it works...  But no idea why it's changing automatically.

Comment: In my VB6 project I referenced MSXML 6.0 on Windows 7. And the msxml6.dll includes also MSXML 3.0. But on Windows 10 MSXML6.dll doesn't inlcudes MSXML 3.0 anymore. In my code I used both MSXML 3.0 types and MSXML 6.0 types. I need both. Sould I create a new question for that problem?